# Type property with enum class meber

Tags: c++

Having the following code

```
enum class EClass { A, B, C, D, E };

template <typename T> struct S;

template <> struct S<EClass::A> {
  static constexpr std::string_view name = "A";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
template <> struct S<EClass::A> {
```

What is wrong with the A member of Eclass? shouldn't it be a type? I'm using c++ 20

Comment: It is a value from the enum, whereas your template requires a type (`typename T`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `EClass::A` is not a type; it's a value of type `EClass`. Enum values in C++ are not treated as types, so you can't specialize a template based on them directly.

If you want to map enum values to corresponding names, you can take a different approach, such as using a function or a variable template instead of a class template specialization.

Here's an example using a constexpr function:

```cpp
enum class EClass { A, B, C, D, E };

constexpr std::string_view getName(EClass e) {
  switch (e) {
    case EClass::A: return "A";
    case EClass::B: return "B";
    case EClass::C: return "C";
    case EClass::D: return "D";
    case EClass::E: return "E";
  }
  return ""; // or throw an exception, or handle it some other way
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use a variable template specialization:

```cpp
enum class EClass { A, B, C, D, E };

template <EClass e> struct S;

template <> struct S<EClass::A> {
  static constexpr std::string_view name = "A";
};

// More specializations...
```

Here, the template parameter `e` is a non-type template parameter, and it's specialized based on the value `EClass::A`, which is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

No. `EClass` is a type, `EClass::A` is a value of type `EClass`, not a type.

You could define your template as `template <EClass T> struct S;`, then it would work (but *only* admit values of type `EClass` as template parameters).